# Magento Logged Error:" Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in...."

Tags: magento, cpanel

I'm getting a logged error withing my magento backend for this about every 5 mins an its using up alot of my site memory because of how frequently this error is logged. What should i do to fix this error?

I have been given a filename and line :

FrontendConfigurableProductMatrix/controllers/CartController.php on line 55

here is the code for lines 50-60:

```
    unset($params['product_matrix']);

    $product_matrix = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_matrix');

    if (count(array_filter($product_matrix['qty'])) == 0) {
        if(count($params['super_attribute']) != 0 && count($params['super_attribute']) == count(array_filter($params['super_attribute']))) {
            $product_matrix = array();
            $product_matrix['qty'] = array( $params['product'] => $params['qty']);
            $product_matrix[$params['product']] = $params;
        } else {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unset($params['product_matrix']);

$product_matrix = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_matrix');

if (is_array($product_matrix['qty']) && count(array_filter($product_matrix['qty'])) == 0) {
if(count($params['super_attribute']) != 0 && count($params['super_attribute']) == count(array_filter($params['super_attribute']))) {
    $product_matrix = array();
    $product_matrix['qty'] = array( $params['product'] => $params['qty']);
    $product_matrix[$params['product']] = $params;
} else {
```